# Apache & MySQL Migrate to other server strategy

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

how should I go about to migrate my database and apache server to another machine? My current system `A.com` is serving a DB API. I need to migrate to machine `B.com` with uninterrupted service to the clients.

What is a good (or standard) strategy to maintain operation? Copy the DB and enable `mod_proxy` or `mod_rewrite` and run A and B in parallel for some time until all users updated to a new client?

Comment: Is the DB these APIs are serving running on a local database or are they all pointing to the same database? Your migration strategy will vary depending on how the API you're referring to functions.

Comment: Both run independent DBs

Comment: Id probably just put up b, update all references from a to b, and use a cname or something to redirect a to b

Comment: I do not think I can set `cname` in Apache, no?

Comment: CNAME is a DNS record type technically, so no, you can't, or just configure apache to use a remote database :)